# Why can't Haskell deduce that this type is correct?

Tags: haskell, types, gadt

I have a simple definition for a Nat and a definition for types indexed by Nat's, Natty.

```
data Nat :: * where 
    Zero :: Nat
    Suc  :: Nat -> Nat

data Natty :: Nat -> * where
    Zy :: Natty Zero
    Sy :: Natty n -> Natty (Suc n)
```

My goal is to create a function that, given a type indexed by Nat n and a type indexed by Nat m, will produce a type indexed by type Nat n + m.

For example, foo (Sy Zy) (Sy $ Sy Zy) = Sy $ Sy $ Sy Zy

Nat addition is simple and is defined as such:

```
nAdd :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
nAdd x  Zero    = x
nAdd x (Suc y)  = Suc $ nAdd x y
```

I had thought that foo would be defined similarly in the following way:

```
foo :: Natty n -> Natty m -> Natty (nAdd n m)
foo x  Zy    = x
foo x (Sy y) = Sy $ foo x y
```

But this leads to an interesting error:

```
Could not deduce: n ~ nAdd n 'Zero
from the context: m ~ 'Zero
```

**Why can't haskell deduce that n ~ nAdd n 'Zero? Is there a simple way to fix this or will a different approach be needed?**

Thanks, any input would be greatly appreciated. The following extensions are also used.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, KindSignatures, GADTs #-}
```

Comment: Haskell is not (currently) dependently typed. You cannot use the value-level function `nAdd` in a type signature. `Natty (nAdd n m)` just treats `nAdd` as a unique, curiously-named type variable. Perhaps you want to use a closed type family instead? Alternatively, the `singletons` library can promote the function to a type family for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @AlexisKing notes, the `nAdd` in the type signature for `foo` is just treated as another type variable (like `m` or `n`) and Haskell doesn't tie it back to the definition of the function `nAdd`.

In Haskell, you can't apply term-level functions (like `nAdd`) to types.  Instead, you need to use type families.  If you define a type-level "function" `NAdd` as a type family:

```
type family NAdd (a :: Nat) (b :: Nat) :: Nat
type instance NAdd n Zero = n
type instance NAdd n (Suc m) = Suc (NAdd n m)
```

then you can use this function in your `foo` signature:

```
foo :: Natty n -> Natty m -> Natty (NAdd n m)
foo x  Zy    = x
foo x (Sy y) = Sy $ foo x y
```

This requires a number of additional extensions to work, and the complete working example (running under GHC 8.2.2) looks like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeInType #-}

import Data.Kind

data Nat :: * where 
    Zero :: Nat
    Suc  :: Nat -> Nat

data Natty :: Nat -> * where
    Zy :: Natty Zero
    Sy :: Natty n -> Natty (Suc n)

type family NAdd (a :: Nat) (b :: Nat) :: Nat
type instance NAdd n Zero = n
type instance NAdd n (Suc m) = Suc (NAdd n m)

nAdd :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
nAdd x  Zero    = x
nAdd x (Suc y)  = Suc $ nAdd x y

foo :: Natty n -> Natty m -> Natty (NAdd n m)
foo x  Zy    = x
foo x (Sy y) = Sy $ foo x y 

test1 = foo (Sy Zy) (Sy $ Sy Zy)
test2 = Sy $ Sy $ Sy Zy
```